# Web app that contains a check-list based task management UI?

Tags: user-interface, checkbox, task-management

I'm looking to develop my own task application so I'm trying to study the UI of any possible in-browser apps that have some sort of functionality which has an ordered list where items can be tagged as "done" and they either get color-highlighted or move into a "DONE" column.

By the way, the area would be a tinyMCE or similar editable area and not some primitive html rendering.

Example:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The To-dos section of [www.basecamphq.com](http://www.basecamphq.com)